# Make job submitted with bsub run in parallel with job that was submitted before and still running

Tags: lsf

I would like the new submitted job to bsub not PEND but start immediate run.
If possible I would like to limit this to N jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want two jobs to run in parallel, its probably best to submit a single parallel job (`bsub -n`) that runs two different processes, potentially on two different hosts.

The LSF admin can force a PENDing job to run with the [brun](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSWRJV_10.1.0/lsf_command_ref/brun.8.html) command.  However, this will cause the execution host to be temporarily overloaded.